# Firebase Firestore transaction is returning a querySnapshot instead of a documentSnapshot

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i'm replicating this code from the firebase documentation in google cloud functions:

```
var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.get(cityRef)
  .then(doc => {
    // Add one person to the city population
    var newPopulation = doc.data().population + 1;
    t.update(cityRef, { population: newPopulation });
  });
}).then(result => {
  console.log('Transaction success!');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```

But i get: `property 'data' does not exist on type 'QuerySnapshot'` when it should be a documentSnapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after i opened an issue on github and get some insight https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/344

```
async function setCounts(storeRef: admin.firestore.DocumentReference) { // Type here

  var transaction = admin.firestore().runTransaction(t => {
    return t.get(storeRef)
    .then((doc: admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => { // Type here
      x = doc.data(); // Now i can get data() from the doc
    });
  }).then(result => {
    console.log('Transaction success!');
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('Transaction failure:', error);
  });

}
```

I finally made it work by explicitly declaring the types for DocumentReference and DocumentSnapshot, i don't know why, but while deploying the linter inferred doc as QuerySnapshot even though it was not.